# how to fix this error "Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['float', 'str']"

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

Here is my code.

```py
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

rainfall['station_name'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(rainfall['station_name'])
```

Comment: According to the error message you have both numbers and strings in the input. Print out what is in `rainfall['station_name']`. You may have to convert all inputs to strings using `str()` or all to numbers using `float()`. Add the input that causes the problem.

Comment: Check for null values.  It will throw this error if you have nulls in that field.

Comment: rainfall['station_name'] = rainfall['station_name'].astype(str)  will do

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have empty values within the columns. This can be checked with:

```
rainfall.isnull().any()
```

If you quickly want to get rid of any and all rows missing values you can use:

```
rainfall= rainfall.dropna()
```

If you only want to remove rows where the station_name is missing use:

```
rainfall.dropna(subset=['rainfall'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
```

In order to resolve this, you need to completely convert your feature i.e., station_name into an str data type.

```
rainfall['station_name'] = rainfall['station_name'].astype(str)
```

Then encode the feature:

```
rainfall['station_name'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(rainfall['station_name'])
```